# Create a dataframe in pandas from the rows following a given record for each ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following Python DataFrame:

| ID | direction | other | color | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | OUT | TT | red | 2022-01-03 |
| 0 | IN | TE | red | 2022-01-03 |
| 0 | OUT | YE | red | 2022-01-04 |
| 0 | IN | PO | red | 2022-01-05 |
| 0 | IN | PT | red | 2022-01-06 |
| 1 | OUT | PO | blue | 2022-01-04 |
| 2 | IN | PO | green | 2022-01-06 |
| 2 | IN | KO | green | 2022-01-07 |
| 3 | IN | XE | red | 2022-01-04 |
| 3 | OUT | PA | red | 2022-01-05 |
| 4 | IN | MY | white | 2022-01-01 |

I want to get a DataFrame from the previous one, such that it gets for each ID, all the rows following the last `direction=OUT` row recorded. If only rows with `direction=IN` exist for an ID, it will also return it in the new DataFrame, even if there is no previous `direction=OUT` row for that ID.

Result from the above example:

| ID | direction | other | color | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | IN | PO | red | 2022-01-05 |
| 0 | IN | PT | red | 2022-01-06 |
| 2 | IN | PO | green | 2022-01-06 |
| 2 | IN | KO | green | 2022-01-07 |
| 4 | IN | MY | white | 2022-01-01 |

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Performance is important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap order in original `DataFrame` by slice `[::-1]`, then use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) with condition `direction='OUT'`, change order by original and pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with invert mask by `~`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[::-1]
df = df[~df1['direction'].eq('OUT').groupby(df1['ID']).cummax().iloc[::-1]]
print (df)
    ID direction other  color        date
3    0        IN    PO    red  2022-01-05
4    0        IN    PT    red  2022-01-06
6    2        IN    PO  green  2022-01-06
7    2        IN    KO  green  2022-01-07
10   4        IN    MY  white  2022-01-01
```

How it working:

Swapping rows:

```
print (df.iloc[::-1])
    ID direction other  color        date
10   4        IN    MY  white  2022-01-01
9    3       OUT    PA    red  2022-01-05
8    3        IN    XE    red  2022-01-04
7    2        IN    KO  green  2022-01-07
6    2        IN    PO  green  2022-01-06
5    1       OUT    PO   blue  2022-01-04
4    0        IN    PT    red  2022-01-06
3    0        IN    PO    red  2022-01-05
2    0       OUT    YE    red  2022-01-04
1    0        IN    TE    red  2022-01-03
0    0       OUT    TT    red  2022-01-03
```

Get cumulative max:

```
print (df1['direction'].eq('OUT').groupby(df1['ID']).cummax())
10    False
9      True
8      True
7     False
6     False
5      True
4     False
3     False
2      True
1      True
0      True
Name: direction, dtype: bool
```

Inverse mask and swap order of values:

```
print (~df1['direction'].eq('OUT').groupby(df1['ID']).cummax().iloc[::-1])
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5     False
6      True
7      True
8     False
9     False
10     True
Name: direction, dtype: bool
```

And last filter by boolean indexing.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can compute a mask using a reverse [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) per group on the 'OUT' values (reversing using the `[::-1]` slice) and use it for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df['direction'].eq('OUT')
        .groupby(df['ID']).apply(lambda s: s[::-1].cummax()[::-1])
       )

df.loc[~mask]
```

alternatively, get the 'OUT' values only and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html) per group to select all the rows prior to an OUT, then use the mask as previously:

```
s = df['direction'].eq('OUT')
mask = s.where(s).groupby(df['ID']).bfill().fillna(False)
df[~mask]
```

output:

```
    ID direction other  color        date
3    0        IN    PO    red  2022-01-05
4    0        IN    PT    red  2022-01-06
6    2        IN    PO  green  2022-01-06
7    2        IN    KO  green  2022-01-07
10   4        IN    MY  white  2022-01-01
```

intermediate mask:

```
df.assign(mask=mask)

    ID direction other  color        date   mask
0    0       OUT    TT    red  2022-01-03   True
1    0        IN    TE    red  2022-01-03   True
2    0       OUT    YE    red  2022-01-04   True
3    0        IN    PO    red  2022-01-05  False
4    0        IN    PT    red  2022-01-06  False
5    1       OUT    PO   blue  2022-01-04   True
6    2        IN    PO  green  2022-01-06  False
7    2        IN    KO  green  2022-01-07  False
8    3        IN    XE    red  2022-01-04   True
9    3       OUT    PA    red  2022-01-05   True
10   4        IN    MY  white  2022-01-01  False
```